# Is there a faster way to do large amounts of random numbers and having a if command for if its 1 or 2

Tags: c#

I'm making a program that needs 55 random numbers at once and a way to sort them by 1s and 2s. Like a number of 1s and a number of 2s without a billion if commands and 55 lines of int num1 = random.Next(1, 3);

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a Histogram.  Have a look for code samples that do that.

Comment: Get one random long then `bit = x&1; x>>1;` in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

55 numbers is not a large amount of numbers to be honest, if you want to keep it simple here is how

```
var random = new Random();
List<int> randomNumbers;

for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
{
    randomNumbers.Add(random.Next(1,3))
}

// i dont actually know what you mean by sorting, but if you want to sort the list
// you can use randomNumbers.Sort()
var ones = randomNumbers.Where(x => x == 1);
var twos = randomNumbers.Where(x => x == 2);
```